# Redhat 7.4 fresh VM add repository for slapd, ldap-utils package

Tags: redhat, yum, repository, packages

I am trying to redo steps from: https://youtu.be/6ls6kRvGkrU?t=100
But there is Ubuntu, and i am wondering can i get the same packages on redhat 7.4?

Currently they are missing:

```
[k@localhost ~]$ sudo yum install slapd
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
No package slapd available.
Error: Nothing to do
[k@localhost ~]$ sudo yum install ldap-utils
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
No package ldap-utils available.
Error: Nothing to do


sudo yum search slapd
[sudo] password for k: 
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
========================================================== Matched: slapd ==========================================================
openldap-servers.x86_64 : LDAP server
```

I was able to install `yum install openldap-servers.x86_64` only.

Answer (score 0):

The `slapd` package you can find in Debian, Ubuntu, and similar distros, is equivalent to the `openldap-servers` you would have with CentOS, RedHat, Fedora, ... Don't get fooled by their name, they both ship with the OpenLDAP server.